# JSOUP login and parsing

Tags: jsoup

I need to get a database size value from tab. URL: http://www.try-phpbb.com/31x/ucp.php?mode=login  For this I need to be logged in twice. Failed to do it even at once.

Trying something like this but no success:

```
 Connection.Response res = Jsoup
                .connect("http://www.try-phpbb.com/31x/ucp.php?mode=login")
                .data("username", "administrator")
                .data("password", "administrator")
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need more info then just username and password to send along in the form. A look in the html of the website shows that the login form also contains some hidden fields, including an input with name `sid`. This seems to be an id generated by the server, so you need to get the login page first, read out this sid (and maybe session cookies) and send this along with your post request. This should do the trick.

1) GET the login page

2) read the cookies, read out the sid. A look into the network Tab in Chrome shows that the site sets the following cookies:

```
phpbb3_ascraeus_90541803_u=1; 
phpbb3_ascraeus_90541803_k=;
phpbb3_ascraeus_90541803_sid=befc4716f8061a422407f4f77207e2a8
```

In Joup you can access the cookies like so:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://www.try-phpbb.com/31x/ucp.php?mode=login")
.execute();
String phpbb3_ascraeus_90541803_sid = res.cookie("phpbb3_ascraeus_90541803_sid");
String rawHTML = res.body();
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(rawHTML);
String sid = doc.select("input[name=sid]").first().attr("value");
```

3) Generate the POST request with cookies, username, password and sid form fields. Like so:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup
    .connect("http://www.try-phpbb.com/31x/ucp.php?mode=login")
    .data("username", "administrator")
    .data("password", "administrator")
    .data("sid", "sid")
    .cookie("phpbb3_ascraeus_90541803_sid", phpbb3_ascraeus_90541803_sid)
    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
    .execute();
```

Note that I did not test this. You may or may not need the cookie. Maybe you need all cookies and also all hidden inputs. Experiment for yourself. This should be enough to help you grasp the idea. The actual coding is your job, right?

Comment: Thank you very much!  But I don't understand how can I read cookies using tje GET??
 I would be very appreaciated if you sent me a piece of code.